# Examples of an indecomposable finitely generated module over a local ring.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a local ring, that is, there is only one $\mathfrak{m}$ maximal ideal. It can be proved that for a  module $M_{R}$ over $R$ which is finitely generated, $M_{R}$ has always a projective cover and if so this projective is given by $\rho:R^{(n)} \to M_{R}$ where $n$ is the dimension of $R/\mathfrak{m}$-module $M/\mathfrak{m}M\cong (R/\mathfrak{m})^{n}$. I want to show an example of an indecomposable finitely generated module over $R$ local so I need $n>1$. I was thinking over vector spaces but this is not gonna work since all indecomposable vector spaces have dimension $1$. Any help showing an example satisfying this will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Take $R=k[[x^2,x^3]]$ and $M$ the maximal ideal.

Comment: Does it works if  I think $k[x^2,x^3]$ rather than the formal power series?@Mohan

Comment: $k[x^2, x^3]$ is not a local ring.

Comment: The maximal ideal for the local ring you proposed is $(x^{2},x^{3})$ right? Still I cannot figure out how $M_{R}$ is finitely generated and also why you compute the dimension of  $K[[x^{2},x^{3}]]/ (x^{2},x^{3})$-module $M/\ (x^{2},x^{3} )M $ to get that is strictly bigger than 1 ? Thanks @Mohan

Comment: Am not sure about your question. The ring in question is Noetherian and any ideal is finitely generated.  To calculate the number of generators, you use Nakayama's lemma.